# Wait for rendering after manual $compile

Tags: angularjs

I have a page with dynamic content. Content depends of a lot of options, so I use manual compiling using $compile. I have a directive like this:

```
function compileHtml($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return scope.$eval(attrs.compileHtml);
            }, function (value) {
                if (value) {
                    element.html(value);
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

There are a lot of DevExtreme charts in compiling HTML. They are in their own directives. 
I need an event after rendering whole page including all charts. I tried to use `$timeout(function () {}` but it fires before rendering charts. It works with hack like this:

```
$timeout(function () { 
    $timeout(function () {
    }
}, 100);
```

But this is not exactly what I want. Could you please suggest something instead?

Comment: There is no such event. You will need to provide more details

Comment: Thanks for commenting. What kind of details would be helpful?